# Drag and drop image, store image ID via ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a drag and drop function, the image should be draggable onto a section and be stored into a "folder". Each folder would have it's own ID. The model is working but now I need some front-end wizardry to make it look good,  similar to how Gmail works where you drag an email into a folder.

This is what I have so far, I managed to get it working with dragging the image onto a textbox, hiding the textbox doesn't have the same effect, though.

HTML Image:

```
 <img id="{{$preview->id}}" draggable="true" src="{{$preview->img_thumb}}" data-zoom-image="{{$preview->img_url}}" data-imgid="{{$preview->id}}" data-imgexp="exposure" class="img-rounded draggie" height="80" width="120"></img>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggie").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 100
  });
  var targetName;
  $(".draggie").mousedown(function(){
    exposure = $(this).attr("data-imgexp");
    id = $(this).attr("data-imgid");
  });
  $("#image-id").droppable({
    accept: ".draggie",
    drop: function(event) {
      $('#image-exp').val($('#image-exp').val() + exposure);
      $('#image-id').val($('#image-id').val() + id);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet or bin? It will much easier for us to understand the question and help you..

Comment: Created this Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9j93xnu2/

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager ? Hard to tell whats going on with the limited description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the [JQuery UI Droppable Demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager), I made the following that you can start with: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9j93xnu2/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
  <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Peaks</h5>
      <img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/278821/252659818/stock-photo-beautiful-view-of-mount-ama-dablam-way-to-everest-base-camp-nepal-252659818.jpg" alt="" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Rock</h5>
      <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1516148/324716942/stock-photo-landscape-of-zhangjiajie-taken-from-old-house-field-located-in-wulingyuan-scenic-and-historic-324716942.jpg" alt="" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1516148/324716942/stock-photo-landscape-of-zhangjiajie-taken-from-old-house-field-located-in-wulingyuan-scenic-and-historic-324716942.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 4</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras4_min.jpg" alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="folder-1" class="folder ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open">Folder</span> Folder 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="folder-2" class="folder ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open">Folder</span> Folder 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="trash" class="folder ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #gallery {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    min-height: 12em;
  }

  .gallery.custom-state-active {
    background: #eee;
  }

  .gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .gallery li h5 {
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .gallery li a {
    float: right;
  }

  .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
    float: left;
  }

  .gallery li img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .folder {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 6em;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .folder h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
  }

  .folder h4 .ui-icon {
    float: left;
  }

  .folder .gallery h5 {
    display: none;
  }
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  // there's the gallery and the trash
  var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
    $trash = $("#trash"),
    $folder_1 = $("#folder-1"),
    $folder_2 = $("#folder-2");

  // let the gallery items be draggable
  $("li", $gallery).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
  });

  // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
  $trash.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      deleteImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  $folder_1.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      moveImage(ui.draggable, event.target.id);
    }
  });
  $folder_2.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      moveImage(ui.draggable, event.target.id);
    }
  });

  // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
  $gallery.droppable({
    accept: "#trash li",
    activeClass: "custom-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      recycleImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });

  // image deletion function
  var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

  function moveImage($item, t) {
    console.log("Image moving to " + t);
    var $target = $("#" + t);
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      var $list = $("ul", $target).length ? $("ul", $target) : $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($target);
      $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
      $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
        $item.animate({
          width: "48px"
        })
        .find("img")
        .animate({
          height: "36px"
        });
      });
    });
  }

  function deleteImage($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
        $("ul", $trash) :
        $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);

      $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
      $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
        $item
          .animate({
            width: "48px"
          })
          .find("img")
          .animate({
            height: "36px"
          });
      });
    });
  }

  // image recycle function
  var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

  function recycleImage($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item
        .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
        .remove()
        .end()
        .css("width", "96px")
        .append(trash_icon)
        .find("img")
        .css("height", "72px")
        .end()
        .appendTo($gallery)
        .fadeIn();
    });
  }

  // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
  function viewLargerImage($link) {
    var src = $link.attr("href"),
      title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
      $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

    if ($modal.length) {
      $modal.dialog("open");
    } else {
      var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
        .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
      setTimeout(function() {
        img.dialog({
          title: title,
          width: 400,
          modal: true
        });
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
  $("ul.gallery > li").click(function(event) {
    var $item = $(this),
      $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
      deleteImage($item);
    } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
      viewLargerImage($target);
    } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
      recycleImage($item);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

This example allows the user to drag an image to a folder, using `moveImage($item, t)` where `$item` is the draggable item and `t` is the target ID. You can update this function to pass the image URL via AJAX to your database to store it in a "folder" or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll test it out but I think it's pushed me in the right direction anyway. Thanks again.